# Dynamically change Login Tab with My Profile tab after the user has logged in

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

On start of the app, the 'Login' bottom tab is displayed. What I'm trying to achieve is to change the displayed tab which is 'Login' into 'My Profile' Tab after the user has logged in the app.

I used Redux to store the app's login status and I managed to get the status but I don't have an idea how to use it to change the tabs dynamically.

Here's the two tabs declared:

```
// MainTabNavigator.js

const LoginStack = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
});

LoginStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarVisible: true,
  tabBarLabel: 'Login',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-link' : 'md-link'}
    />
  ),
}

const MyProfileStack = createSwitchNavigator({
  MyProfile: HomeScreen,
});

MyProfileStack.navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
  tabBarVisible: true,
  tabBarLabel: 'My Profile',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-person' : 'md-person'}
    />
  ),
})

export default createBottomTabNavigator({ LoginStack })
```

I tried creating another component and connect it then import it on the tabs page file but I can't use the returned value of the IsLoggedIn().

```
// IfLoggedIn.js

function IsLoggedIn(props) {
  return props.loginState.isLoggedIn ? true : false
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ loginState }) => ({
  loginState
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({
  setLoginState
}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(IsLoggedIn)
```

I was thinking that I can use it in the tabs page file like this:

```
// MainTabNavigator.js

const InterChangeTab = IsLoggedIn ? MyProfileStack : LoginStack
export default createBottomTabNavigator({ InterChangeTab })
```

But it did not work because IsLoggedIn is a component and not a regular function.

Comment: setting it to a state with rerender.

Comment: @SnehaBharti I think we have the same issue using state: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1171, How do you rerender react navigation?

Comment: yes.. build 2 function.. 1 for before login and one after login and make them work using condition

Comment: @SnehaBharti I'm sorry I don't understand, where would I create the 2 functions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not return your `LoginStack` or `MyProfileStack` straight on your `IfLoggedIn`?

```js
function IsLoggedIn(props) {
  return ({props.loginState.isLoggedIn ? <MyProfileStack /> : <LoginStack />})
}
```

Actually IMO, I prefer to use another switchNavigator to switch between login screen and my contents screens, checkout [this react navigation docs on authentication flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

Comment: I tried that but it says: 'The navigation prop is missing for this navigator. In react-navigation 3 you must set up your app container directly'

Comment: Have you [use `createAppContainer` on your root navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/#explicit-app-container-required-for-the-root-navigator)?

Comment: Yeah it's on AppNavigator.js file `export default createAppContainer(MainTabNavigator);` and then I use it like this <AppNavigator  /> in the App.js file

Comment: I believe you are trying the authentication flow in the docs? Can you share your entire navigator stacks you have, as well as from where are you trying to call the `navigation` prop?

Comment: Here's my file structure: https://snack.expo.io/@iah.buenacosa/dynamically-changing-tabs-(not-working). I updated the code based on the docs. The `createAppContainer(MainTabNavigator)` is now in the App.js

Comment: Hey, i just went through your code. I have 1 advice, you can totally get rid of your `IfLoggedIn.js` and include both you login and profile stack on `MainTabNavigator`.

Comment: To navigate, you can either check for your state on `componentDidUpdate` of your `login` screen and then [navigate to profile](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#navigate-link-to-other-screens), or (IMO even better) [dispatch an navigate action](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#navigate) in you redux action where you check and confirm the login is successful.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the dispatch an navigate action in you redux action where you check and confirm the login is successful? Am I going to put the dispatch inside the redux action creator? How will the `MainTabNavigator` know how to change tabs? Thank you very much for helping!

Comment: [Check this out, navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html). And yes, you can call `NavigationService.navigate('Login')` in your redux action function